# why was Prophet Muhammad surprised to see Jibril?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, seerah

Okay, so i can't understand one thing, that is when angel jibril came down on cave hira the first time, why was the prophet [PBHU]so shocked, didn't he have his breast open and heart taken out already when he was small ? why did no one pay attention to such stories before he became a prophet ? makes me wonder if hadiths are authentic.

Comment: Have you read the seerah in any known source and the corresponding reports, or are you asking out of the blue?

Comment: @Medi1Saif no i haven't read the entire seerah, i was reading raheeq al makhtoom, but this question bothered me,  i really need answers, because i dont know to reconcile with this.

Comment: OK, let's say it this way just because the prophet later reported about the "breast opening" doesn't mean that he knew at the time of the incident that what happened was something good or letting expect to be somebody special.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It is quite hard to believe that prophet saw leggit had his heart open and Abu Hurayrah even saw it, yet they just moved on ??  I think there must be a good answer to this which am not aware of, imagine if you see two angels descending and opening your friends heart, wouldn't you be shocked ?

Comment: Abu Hurayra accepted Islam 2 or 3 years before the death of the prophet and he came from far away (he's from the tribe of Daws), he certainly didn't witness this, but might have heard it from the prophet.

Comment: Oh i see, it said abu hurayra reported the hadith my bad, anyways still why was he surprized to see Jibril when he already had his breast open by an angel ?

Comment: Even after chest been opened and heart washed, we can see our beloved prophet Muhammad ﷺ felt all the human emotions, fear, sadness, anger, etc. He is human after all, so being scared or shocked to see a person in such a secluded place is pretty normal. As @Medi1Saif has mentioned, if you read the seerah/biography of prophet (ﷺ) will clear all your doubts regarding this matter. In Sha Allah.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem Jazakallah khair brother, i will Inshallah

Comment: Hey bro, I honestly don't understand how you would expect him **not** to be shocked? Imagine entering a remote cave in isolation, far away from the filth of paganism in Arabia at that time, and suddenly this overwhelming figure shows up to you alone, and starts speaking to you. This is literally the most natural reaction ever. I would actually be shocked if he was okay with it as if it was like any other casual talk. Take the context into perspective brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prophet [PBUH] fainted according to the Hadeeth of the breast opening: https://sunnah.com/muslim:162c

So he didn't tell anyone about Jibreel in his childhood since **he had no idea what happened at that time!**

Jibreel indeed must have told the Prophet about the needle marks in his chest after his prophethood, not before it, Muhammad didn't even know Jibreel before he reaches 40 years old, in the same way Moses [AS] never spoke with Allah before becoming a Prophet at 40 years old:

20:12

> إِنِّىٓ أَنَا۠ رَبُّكَ فَٱخْلَعْ نَعْلَيْكَ ۖ إِنَّكَ بِٱلْوَادِ
> ٱلْمُقَدَّسِ طُوًى
>
> *Indeed, I am your Lord, so remove your sandals. Indeed, you are in the blessed valley of Ṭuwā.*

If you still doubt the meeting between the Prophet and Jibreel, then remember that not only the Qur'an speaks about them in Surat Al-Najm [chapter 53], but even the Bible mentions a prophecy about it:

> Isaiah 29:12 And the book is delivered to him that is not learned,
> saying, Read this, I pray thee: **and he saith, I am not learned.**

ما أنا بقارئ

Comment: ohh, Jazakallah khair brother, thanks...